# obtaining textual data from a single column in dataframe

Tags: r, readline, quanteda

I want to read as text only one specific column of my dataframe, i.e. the 3rd column C, and create a word cloud. Let `df=`

```
A B C
1 2 sheep
2 2 sheep
3 4 goat
4 5 camel
5 2 camel
6 1 camel
```

I am try to readLines from `readLines(df$C)` but I get the following error:

```
 Error in readLines(df$C) : 
  'con' is not a connection
```

Comment: Don't you just want `df$C` ?

Comment: If you already have this as a data frame, does `df$C` not get what you're looking for?

Comment: `readLines` is for reading lines of information from a file. If I'm understanding this correctly, you already have a data frame, so you don't need to read anything into your session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("A B C
1 2 sheep
2 2 sheep
3 4 goat
4 5 camel
5 2 camel
6 1 camel"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.3.0

corpus(df, text_field = "C") %>%
    dfm() %>%
    textplot_wordcloud(min_count = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: just for a curiosity, is there a straightforward way to remove punctuations and stop words in the text analyzed?

Comment: Yes, in the. `dfm()` call you can pass arguments to `tokens()` - see `?tokens` - and one of the `dfm()` arguments is `remove` (for removing stopwords).